# Behavior callbacks and contain conflict

Tags: cakephp

I made a `TranslatableBehavior` with an `afterFind()` function to modify my output, and it works as I want it to, but only on primary results. When I call the model as contained to another model, the callback function does not activate.

My structure is like this:

```
Category hasMany CategoryDynamic (dynamic table contains the translations).
Category hasMany Item
Item hasMany ItemDynamic (again, here are the item translations)
```

Both `Category` and `Item` have the Translatable behavior. When I make the following query:

```
$current = $this->Category->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('Category.id' => $root),
    'contain' => array(
        'CategoryDynamic', 
        'Item' => array(
            'ItemDynamic'
        ),
    ),
));
```

it is called for the categories, and not the items. Is there a way I can make this work with contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the main Model (`Category` in your case) will trigger the callback.

Unfortunately, if you want to trigger the callback for the others, you'll need to run separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the fields for other models.

If you are using TranslateBehavior in alongside containable issue, be sure to set the ‘fields’ key for your queries. Otherwise you could end up with invalid SQL generated.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html

Comment: I guess you misunderstood the question, I am not using the default Translate behavior from CakePHP, Translatable is my custom behavior and the problem does not have much to do with what the behavior does. Thanks for your effort anyway, Dave provided the answer I needed.